# Kamailio+rtpengine+SIP.js Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint

Tags: webrtc, rtp, sip-server, kamailio, coturn

I just install Kamailio 4.4.5 + RTPEngine on Ubuntu Server 16.04

all config copy from https://github.com/whisk/WEBRTC-to-SIP

And using SIP.js latest version to make call between 2 chrome browser.

SIP user register successfully and can using text chat 
But when User Invite another user any his Accept call, get this error

Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint.

How to solve this issue???

Answer (score 1):

Use `sdp_with_transport_like(...)` instead of `sdp_with_transport(...)`, because the transport string is `UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF` and the second function is doing an exact match, but the parameter in referred example is only `RTP/SAVPF`.